# Design software architecture

Tags: software-development, visual-design

Are there any good applications that I can use to design the architecture for my software in a visual environment?

I don't like to use pen and paper for this mostly because I change my mind a lot. I always get new ideas on how to do the initial approach in a better way and I would have to redraw all my architecture again.

Most of the times I just end up doing the architecture in my head and write down the important notes. This works with small projects but as it gets bigger I need to be more organized.

I am looking for something like this:
[image]

Comment: [Visual Paradigm](https://www.visual-paradigm.com)

Comment: There are dozens, you need to give us a bit more to go on. Are you following a particular design methodology for example? Do you use UML?